# How to check words use regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Given a string `python php ruby javascript jsonp perhapsphpisoutdated`, how to filter the words that contain `p` but not contain `ph`?

I wrote this regular expression:

```
var reg = /\b\w*p(?!h)\w*\b/;
```

However, the above also matches words like `php` or `ph****p**` so it's not exact? How should I write the regular expression?

Comment: `str.split(' ').filter( x => x.includes('p') && !x.includes('ph'))`

Comment: The concensus is that ["give me a regex that does X” questions should be closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using lookaheads:

```
(?=\w*p)(?!\w*ph)\b(\w+)\b
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/TemmJp/1)

[Regular Expression Resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

---

**Breakdown**:

```
\b(\w+)\b // Looks for word characters (\w) separated by word boundaries
(?=\w*p) // Asserts each word found contains a "p" (positive lookahead)
(?!\w*ph) //Asserts each word found does not contain "ph" (negative lookahead)
```